# Video.js not playing only audio with black screen

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I have initialized video js player on my webpage 
and i have a function that is triggered on a button click to load source to the video . and show the player and start playing it (auto start is set to true)

```
function playVid(x) {
            videojs("vidPlay").src({type: "video/mp4", src: "http://www.domain.com/getVid?id=" + x});
            showPlayer();
        }
```

this works very well in firefox but in other browsers it only plays the audio with black video...
what is wrong here ?
how can i fix this ?

Comment: I hope this link will help you.

[HTML5 video only works in IE. The other browsers shows the black screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360830/html5-video-only-works-in-ie-the-other-browsers-shows-the-black-screen)

Comment: So many duplicate questions for this but no solution provided!